# Good Book for Managing a Linux Web Server?

Tags: apache, server, mysql, webserver, lamp

I'm being thrust into the role of managing my own web server. I will have access to some managed support, but I need a comprehensive resource I can turn to that covers: command line basics, apache and mysql db administration. I don't need to be an expert in any of these, but I need to know how to work my way around and make changes when needed. I have some experience with mamp and wamp, but I'd like to have a good handbook for more serious work in this area.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good overview, covers many areas:  http://www.admin.com/

My 2 cents: There's no substitute for learning by doing, no book will tell you everything you need.  Most common problems you'll have are well documented, you just need to encounter them so as to learn how to solve them for next time.

Comment: I ordered it. Do I'll see how it works out. Thx

Answer (score 1):

For starters, review The Linux Documentation Project's [Guides](http://tldp.org/guides.html) (at a minimum, if you have a managed service, skim a guide on system administration)

Next, as there are many flavors of Linux with idiosyncratic package managers or processes (RHEL vs Debian, for example) become familiar with the documentation for the flavor of Linux you will be using.

Once you are confident with your skills at the bash prompt and can install, configure, and remove software, make it a point to familiarize yourself (at the very least) with the daemons your server will rely upon to serve your site.

- If you are using an unmanaged host, you should read the user guides (or, where there are none, the manual pages) for *every* daemon which will be running on the server to ensure a basic level of security and performance (the initial investment in learning will pay off when problems arise)
- If you are using a managed hosting service, you should (at a bare minimum) review the documentation for your web server daemon - e.g. the user guides available for [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) or [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) to ensure that you are able to configure your server to do what you want it to